# из-за нескольких виджетов на экране неправильно считываются координаты мышки pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

всем привет, делаю аналог paint на pyqt. Почему то мышка рисует как то странно, как будто ошибается с координатами. Буду благодарна за помощь в исправлении.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QFileDialog, QColorDialog, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter, QPen, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QSize
 
 
class PaintApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Paint")
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 1200, 1200)
 
        size = self.label.size()
        canvas = QPixmap(size)
        canvas.fill(Qt.white)
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
 
        self.brush_color = Qt.black
        self.brush_size = 4
 
        self.create_menu()
 
    def create_menu(self):
        main_menu = self.menuBar()
 
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None:
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return
 
        painter = QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        painter.end()
        self.update()
 
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()
 
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PaintApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Imcoocooou, а что такое `untitled.ui` ?

Comment: файл с дизайном qt designer

Comment: Imcoocooou, понятно, а почему вы его не опубликовали? Без него ваш пример невоспроизводимый.